# Evaluate $\sin(\sin(\cdots\sin(\sin(a)+a)\cdots+a)+a)$ limit as the number of terms goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I need help evaluating this limit:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty }\underbrace{\sin( \sin( \cdots \sin( \sin(}_{\text{$n$ compositions}}\,\underbrace{a)+a)\cdots +a)+a)}_{\text{$n$ compositions}},$$

I know that it converges to a specific number, for example when one takes a to be $1$, the limit is at $0.9345632\ldots$

Comment: Hint: If you prove convergence, then the limit $L$ satisfies $L = \sin(L + a)$. However even then, I'm not sure if you can analytically solve that equation. (I'm not saying it's impossible, I just haven't really thought about it). Also you would need to show the solution is unique but that shouldn't be hard.

Comment: So basically it is a fix point iteration with $x_{n+1} = f(x_n) = \sin(x_n+a)$ starting with $x_0=0$?

Comment: @mvw: the most outer function is $\sin( ... + a)$

Answer (score 3):

Write $b_0=a$, $b_{n+1} = \sin(b_n+a)$. We are searching for the fixed points of this sequence $b_n$. This is the limit $L$. Thus the limit $L$, assuming it existence and such*, satisfies $L=\sin(L+a)$. I can't give a closed form for $L$.

*You said you know that it converges to a number, so I don't include that.

Comment: "statistifies", an awesome new word, kudos.

Comment: @orion Ugh, it appears that I've written that wrong more then once. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive version is
\begin{align}
x_0 &= 0 \\
x_{n+1} &= \sin(x_n + a)
\end{align}

A fixed point of $f(x) = \sin(x + a)$ will fulfill
$$
x^* = f(x^*) = \sin(x^* + a)
$$
and this would be needed for 
$$
x_{n+1} - x_n = \sin(x_n + a) - x_n
$$
to vanish.

The case for $a=1$ is shown in the following image:

[image: fixed point iteration for a = 1]

with a fixed point at $x^* \approx 0.93456$.

Comment: You mean the present one or the one before? (See old revisions).

Comment: Yes, I read your old version. It exactly the same now. Nice answer btw, I'm a fan of good plots:)

Comment: I just made an accidental discovery about the software - GeoGebra - I hit the up or down arrow button and it added +1/-1 to the function and the whole construction with arrows etc adapted to the new fixed point (which I defined as cut between the function and it) then left/right and it added +1/-1 to the argument and again the whole construction shifted appropriately.  Very cool stuff, I still only know a fraction of it.